# Referer checking failed - http://localhost:8000/admin/ does not match https://localhost:8000/

Tags: django

> Referer checking failed - http://localhost:8000/admin/ does not match https://localhost:8000/.

I'm getting Forbidden when using runserver and connecting to localhost for no apparent reason. Any idea why?

Comment: When did you started getting these errors, and what did you add/change to get them? Look at what you did and hopefully you will find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the computer resolved the issue for me, I'm still not sure why it was happening though.